# Two Google Analitycs, one with AutLinker

Tags: google-analytics, double, universal-analytics

I have two sites:
example-1.com
example-2.com

I need to have one analitycs (UA-XXXXXXXX-2) only for page example-1.com.

However I also need GA (UA-XXXXXXXX-1) which will be implemented on both sites. Is this code ok for that?
I want to implement it only to site example-1.com ; site example-2.com has only one analiytics so it is done via GTM (with allow linker also).

```
        <script>
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');


        ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true}, {name: 'First'});
        ga('First.require', 'linker');
        ga('linker:autoLink', ['example-1.com', 'example-2.com'] );
        ga('First.require', 'displayfeatures');
        ga('First.send', 'pageview');


        ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-2', {name: 'Second'});
        ga('Second.require', 'displayfeatures');
        ga('Second.send', 'pageview');

    </script>
```